# onclick li submit form and post data-id of li

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to create a small form that submits a `data-id` of a `li` and passes a value onclick `li`. Here's what I've did so far..

```
<form method="POST" action="/default/index" id="event-notify-form">
    <div id="notification-event" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 400px">
    <ul>
    <li data-id="171" class="nav-message-body"></li>
    <li data-id="168" class="nav-message-body"></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

my jquery is

```
$('#notification-event li').click(function() {
    var eid=$(this).attr("data-id");
    $('#event-notify-form').append(eid).submit();  
});
```

data-id is not post , i tried `$_POST` it display empty array

Comment: you need to have a hidden input element with a name, then set its value to the `data-id` attribute value

Comment: That is an invalid markup `li` cannot have a `div` as a parent wrapper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a hidden input element and set its value like

```
<form method="POST" action="/default/index" id="event-notify-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="myId" />
    <div id="notification-event" style="overflow: hidden; width: auto; height: 400px">
        <li data-id="171" class="nav-message-body"></li>
        <li data-id="168" class="nav-message-body"></li>
    </div>
</form>
```

then

```
$('#notification-event li').click(function () {
    var eid = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var $frm = $('#event-notify-form');
    //set the value of the hidden element
    $frm.find('input[name="myId"]').val(eid);
    //submit the form
    $frm.submit();
});
```

in the server side

```
$_POST('myId')
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing to:

```
$('#notification-event li').click(function() {
    var eid=$(this).attr("data-id");
    $('#event-notify-form').append("<input />", {
        "type" : "hidden",
        "value" : eid,
        "name" : "some_name"
    });
    $('#event-notify-form').submit();  
});
```